# How to add data in array of strings in C#

Tags: c#

I have a text box where I'm getting url, for ex:

http://www.amazon.com/black-series-650.

Now I would like to add /en black-series-650 an it looks like.My ouput should be like this.

http://www.amazon.com/en/black-series-650.

Comment: I don't clearly understand your question but are you looking something like `urls[urls.Length -1]` ?

Comment: You could also find the last occurence by using `string.LastIndexOf` instead of splitting https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx

Comment: `string[] urls.Add(txt_OriginalUri.Text.Split('/'));`?

Comment: what type of `txt_OriginalUri`?

Comment: Regarding the situation your are facing, think about using a List<string> instead of an array. Using a list allows you to freely insert or delete elements a confortable way. Once your list is ready, just use string.Join to rebuild a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you can apply for url like :

http://www.amazon.com/black-series-650/abc/ed/aaa

You can try this code :

```
var url = "http://www.amazon.com/black-series-650"; 
// var url = txt_OriginalUri.Text;

var tempUrl = url.Replace("http://", string.Empty);
var lastSlashIndex = tempUrl.IndexOf('/');

var resultUrl = "http://" + tempUrl.Insert(lastSlashIndex + 1, "en/");
```

Comment: How can I remove en if gives before adding it

Comment: Base on lastSlashIndex  and tempUrl , you can replate "en" by string empty

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmp = OriginalUri.Text;
var en = tmp.Replace("http://www.amazon.com", "http://www.amazon.com/en");
var lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add(OriginalUri.Text);
lst.Add(en);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing urls with `Split` function you should parse your url using System.Uri. Check the url segments and re-construct as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
string str = "http://www.amazon.com/black-series-650";
str = str.Insert(str.LastIndexOf("/"),"/en");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to find the last occurence by using `string.LastIndexOf` instead of splitting:

```
string url = txt_OriginalUri.Text;
int idx = url.LastIndexOf('/');
string newUrl = url.Insert(idx,"/en");
```